# Can someone help me with my frontend script issue? I need to know if this is the only way to code this script or if there are better ways

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am a frontend developer working on script injection. Below is how I usually inject the script using Adobe Target but there are quite a few issues with this method:

1.Hard to debug coz my code editor is not recognizing the HTML and CSS in the JS file because my HTML and CSS are wrapped inside ' ' and + in the each line, so if you have done typo or miss something in the code like "position:reltive" in the CSS or HTML then you need to go through all the lines to find what's wrong.

2.As code grows it's hard to keep track of everything.

3.Since it's all in one JS file my code editor is useless with extension and other features(compiler) and I have to manually add ' ' each line by myself and + at the end of each line which is really annoying especially with the 1000 lines of code.

So anyone knows any better way to have HTML+CSS in a js file but yet code editor compile the code or extension for VSCode that can compile HTML + CSS inside JS to make my life a little easier?
I know it's unconventional method but I'm looking for better way to do it if anyone out there doing the same thing in a better way

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';

//CSS GOES HERE //This is an example
var css = '.container-fluid {' +
    'height: 400px;' +
    'background-color: black;' +
    'position: relative;'+
    'float: right;'+
    'width: 20%;'+
    'text-align: center;'+
    'right: 230px;'+
'}' ;

if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    var script = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(style, script);

const anyvar =
  '<div id="container-fluid">' +
  
  //HTML CONTENT GOES HERE

  '</div>';

// INSERT HTML CONTENT USING JQuery

$(anyvar).insertAfter(".someclass");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd split the code up into multiple files, and use a module bundler to interpolate it into the JS. This is the technique [I use](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/One-Click-VTC/src/insertStyle.ts) for exactly this problem.

One approach is with Webpack. With the npm package `raw-loader`, you can start with a CSS file, say

```
/* styles.css */
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Then you can import it and assign it to the `.textContent` of the `<style>` tag:

```
import styleTextCss from './styleText.css';

/// styleTextCss is now a string containing the entire contents
// of the above file

// ...

style.textContent = styleTextCss;
```

It takes a bit of setting up, but it's well worth it, especially for anything that isn't completely trivial.

(This also makes integrating a preprocessor into the development process quite easy, if you wish to go that route - it can make things more organized and less repetitive)

The same exact technique works for HTML.

Having standalone files with the proper file extensions allows for live syntax highlighting and validation.

Comment: Thank you! I checked Webpack and how all the files are bundled together but if you notice my code I am not using a whole html file with head and body tag, I only create div that I want to inject so is it possible to bundle HTML with only the div I am going to inject on top of any website and CSS alone in a .js file using webpack? If Yes, do you have any clear documentation of how this is done? All the tutorial videos are unnecessary bundling SCSS and other stuffs but nobody shows how to bundle the files into one .js that can be injected directly from a browser console or using Adobe Target.

Comment: Just to make it clear I am not creating a web application, I just injecting scripts on top of existing webpage. For e.g. if my client ask me to change the color of a button from white to red, I will just inject the script through Adobe Target to change the color of the button since I don't have access to source code repo of the actually webpage. Just keep that in mind!

Comment: I thought I mentioned everything necessary in my answer. If you want a live demo, you can check out the link in my answer, which links to a repo that uses that technique: https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/One-Click-VTC/src/insertStyle.ts All you need is the raw-loader package (with Webpack), then you can write the HTML or CSS in their own files, then `import` them and you'll have the plain strings from the files available for the JS to use.